# Update image won't work

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to update some data with image. The other data is updated but the image still not updated. here's my code

route

```
Route::get('film/{idFilm}/edit', array('as' => 'film.edit', 'uses' => 'FilmController@edit'));

Route::post('film/{idFilm}/update', array('as' => 'film.update', 'uses' => 'FilmController@update'));
```

controller

```
public function edit($idFilm)
{
    $film = Film::findOrFail($idFilm);
    $genre = Genre::lists('namaGenre', 'idGenre');
    if (is_null($film))
    {
        return Redirect::to('film');
    }
    return View::make('pengelolaan.film.editfilm', compact('film','genre'));
}


/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */
public function update($idFilm)
{
    $rules = array(
    'judulFilm' => 'required',
    'durasi' => 'required|numeric',
    'keterangan' => 'required',
    'idGenre' => 'required'
    );

    $validation = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);
     if ($validation->fails()) 
     {   
        return Redirect::to('film/' . $idFilm . '/edit')
        ->withErrors($validation)
        ->withInput()
        ->with('message', 'There were validation errors.');
      } 
      else 
      {
            $films = Film::find($idFilm);
            $films->judulFilm=Input::get('judulFilm');
            $films->durasi=Input::get('durasi');
            $films->keterangan= Input::get('keterangan');
            $films->idGenre= Input::get('idGenre');
            if(Input::hasFile('foto'))
            {
                $file=Input::file('foto');
                $file->move('img',$file->getClientOriginalName());
                $filename=$file->getClientOriginalName();
                $films->foto = $filename;
                $films->save();
            }
            else
            {
                $films->save();
            }

            Session::flash('message', 'Data Berhasil Diubah');
            return Redirect::to('film');
      }
}
```

view

```
 {{Form::model($film, array('route'=>array('film.update', $film->idFilm,'files' => TRUE)))}}
             <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    {{ Form::label('judulFilm', 'Judul Film') }}
                    {{ Form::text('judulFilm', Input::old('judulFilm'), array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    {{ Form::label('durasi', 'Durasi Film') }}
                    {{ Form::text('durasi', Input::old('durasi'), array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    {{ Form::label('keterangan', 'Sinopsis Film') }}
                    {{ Form::textarea('keterangan', Input::old('keterangan'), array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    {{ Form::label('idGenre', 'Genre') }}
                    {{ Form::select('idGenre', $genre,'',array('class'=>'form-control')) }}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    {{ Form::label('foto', 'Poster') }}
                    {{ Form::file('foto') }}
                </div>
            </div>
            </br>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <a class="btn btn-default " href="{{ url('film') }}">Batal</a>
                    {{Form::submit('Simpan', array('type'=>'submit', 'class'=>'btn btn-default'))}}
            {{Form::close()}}
```

There's no error so i don't know whats wrong with it.
Can someone please tell me what's wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: Where do you save the location of your photo?

Comment: @Jessedegans i save it in public/img folder

Comment: I mean where in your model are you saving the location of your image?

Comment: Are you getting the value in $filename ?

Comment: Does your code goes inside if(Input::hasFile('foto')) { } condition ?

Comment: Did you add  your image field to $fillable property in model?

Comment: @Muthu17 no, it won't run the if(Input::hasFile('foto')) { } condition

Comment: Does your form have enctype attribute(enctype="multipart/form-data") or not?

Comment: @mcklayin yes i put it in $fillable property in model

Comment: @Muthu17 i use 'files' => TRUE

Comment: Check my command http://stackoverflow.com/a/42832070/4049692

Answer (score 0):

There are few possibilities to face this issue :

1. Check for have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute
2. Check your file size. If your file size is too high increase `upload_max_filesize`
3. May be permission dined for your tmp folder. Provide permission for your tem folder. `ini_get('upload_tmp_dir');`

Comment: I try all but still the image won't change

Comment: try dump(Input::all()) and check if any values for file

Comment: there's Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on null error

Comment: Still not getting how you refer to the image... I mean you have to replace it by deleting the old one and naming the new one like the old one. Or you have to change the location record in the database.

Comment: @SekarAnindya I cant because its still unclear how you actually manage to save your image in the first place and where you expect to show the image